# Why is sudo running so many times?

Tags: sudo

I've just noticed that my mac has loads of sudo processes running – why? What is causing them?

[image: Lots of sudos!]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to determine what's going on here is to open a terminal and run

```
ps aux | grep sudo
```

On my machine there are many lines, all that include:

```
/usr/libexec/StartupItemContext /usr/bin/open -a /Library/Application Support/iStat Server/DiskTool.app
```

So, we know that it's from a start up item, specficially iStat Server.

As I don't use that app anymore, I'll uninstall it.